# Adding a filter in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following model -

```
class NetworkAdministrator (models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    admin_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Network(models.Model):
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    network_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(NetworkAdministrator)
```

In the admin panel, for any network I add, it shows **all** administrators, as if it were doing --
`NetworkAdministrator.objects.all()`.

How would I make it so for each specific network, the set of administrators would only include those from the current network --

`Network.objects.get(network='**network name**').administrators.all()`

Functionally speaking, this is what I want to be able to do in the admin panel:

```
1) add network = 'China'
2) add 2 administrators to this network = cadmin1, cadmin2, cadmin3
3) add network = 'India'
4) add 2 administrators to this network: iadmin1, iadmin2 
   (no administrators should show from the China network).
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

```
class AdministrationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Network.administrators.through

class NetworkAdministratorAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    inlines = [
        AdministrationInline,
    ]

class NetworkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AdministrationInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('administrators',)

admin.site.register(Network, NetworkAdmin)
admin.site.register(NetworkAdministrator, NetworkAdministratorAdmin)
```

Please note the `through` intermediary model and the manual exclusion of `'administrators'`

Comment: This is a ManyToMany relationship, not a Foreign Key. When trying to do the method you specified I get an error that says `<class 'myproject.app.models.NetworkAdministrator'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'myproject.app.models.Network'>` and in looking at the doc link, the TabularInline only works for FK.

Comment: My mistake. I found something in the docs though. I updated the link and the example.